# Selenium getCurrentUrl not changing after get

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Sometimes after calling `driver.get(feedUrl)`, `driver.getCurrentUrl()` returns the previous url. Why is this?

Code extract:

```
while((feedItem = sharedQueue.poll()) != null){
    final String feedUrl = feedItem.getLink();

    logger.info("Driver getting " + feedUrl);
    driver.get(feedUrl);

    final String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    logger.info("Driver got feedUrl: " + feedUrl + " from driverUrl: " + url );
}
```

Log extract:

```
12:59:56 [Scrapper 7] INFO  ArticleScrapper - Driver getting http://www.walesonline.co.uk/news/local-news/world-war-two-evacuee-re-10455706
13:03:59 [Scrapper 7] INFO  ArticleScrapper - Driver got feedUrl: http://www.walesonline.co.uk/news/local-news/world-war-two-evacuee-re-10455706 from driverUrl: http://www.walesonline.co.uk/news/local-news/world-war-two-evacuee-re-10455706
13:03:59 [Scrapper 7] INFO  ArticleScrapper - Driver getting http://www.southwalesargus.co.uk/news/14040777.Delays_to_Newport_s_Welsh_school_could_mean_new_pupils_taught_at_primary/?ref=rss
13:04:42 [Scrapper 7] INFO  ArticleScrapper - Driver got feedUrl: http://www.southwalesargus.co.uk/news/14040777.Delays_to_Newport_s_Welsh_school_could_mean_new_pupils_taught_at_primary/?ref=rss from driverUrl: http://www.walesonline.co.uk/news/local-news/world-war-two-evacuee-re-10455706
```

As you can see, the last log entry has the correct feedUrl, but the previous driverUrl

Comment: Have you tried waiting until the page is fully loaded before taking the current url?

Comment: @debugger89 How would you recommend is best to do that?

Answer (score 0):

To wait for the page load, you could explicitly wait for a JavascriptExecutor thingy to execute, along the lines of

```
((JavascriptExecutor) myDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for driver.get to finish loading. There are different wait techniques you can use for this - referred to as implicit and explicit waits.

See here: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Personally I would use the explicit wait:

```
WebDriver driver = // your driver...;
driver.get(feedUrl);
WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```